# Selecting more than 1 F'string in dataframe. python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample code using google calendar API that requires data to be a string value. Instead of manually typing strings each time the data frame is changed I use df.iat. This is what I have so far and works fine for a single value.

```
Create an event
"""
event = {
  'summary':f'{df.iat[0,0]}',
  'description': f'{df.iat[0,1]}',
  'start': {
    'date': '2022-04-04',
  },
  'end': {
    'date': '2022-04-04',
```

which prints out

```
summary = Order
description = Plastic Cups
date 04-04-2022
```

But I need to pull multiple values into a string. How do I perform this to work properly
for example in the description

```
I want to do f'{df.iat[1,1]}',f'{df.iat[0,1]}'
which would print out description = 7000  Plastic Cups
```

but I get errors using this and I've tried dfiloc, I've also tried just a sample

```
(("test"),(f'{df.iat[0,1]}')
```

this only prints off the 'test' portion and not the df.iat string

I've been stuck at this for hours any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can include, inside the formatted string, as many variables as you want. For example: `f"some info: {df.iat[1,1]}, some other info {df.iat[0,1]}"`.

Comment: wow, I can't believe I missed that formatting.. Thank you so much please post an answer so i can vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f-strings in Python, also known as Literal String Interpolation, can handle multiple variables at the same time. For example:

```py
orderID = 012345
orderName = "foo"

message = f"Your order {orderName} with orderID {orderID} was registered!"
```

If you print the aforementioned `message` variable: 
`Your order foo with orderID 012345 was registered!`

For more info regarding this: [PEP-0498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/)